# Why is this happening to my rig?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

I am following a tutorial about rigging a mesh and when looking at the weight painting, I noticed this problem.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev0tX.jpg

Can anyone explain what is happening??

Thank you.

Comment: You might have to click the very bottom bone and subtract the weights for that bone. It's possible the very bottom bone is controlling the bottom foot and thus preventing the vertices from moving